# Too many Back buttons swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I am making a app and there are too many back buttons in my navigation view

Arabic is at the bottom

They are all in the same navigation view

Please help

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        NavigationLink("Arabic"){
            Arabic()
        }
        NavigationLink("English"){
            English()
        }
        NavigationLink("Coptic"){
            Coptic()
        }
        NavigationLink ("Hazzat / Lyrics"){
            Hazzat()
        }
    }
}

NavigationView {
    List {
        NavigationLink("Liturgy"){
            ArLiturgy()
        }
        NavigationLink("Offering of Incense"){
            English()
        }
        NavigationLink("Tasbeha"){
            English()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do your `Arabic()`, `English()`, etc. views have their own `NavigationView`s?  If so, don't do that.

Comment: No they are all in one NavigationView but separate NavigationLinks but thanks

Comment: Your code does not demonstrate the problem.  You need to add a minimal example that shows the problem.  At a minimum, you need to include code for `Arabic()`, `English()`, etc.

Comment: Most apps only need `NavigationView`, `TabView` and sheets are exceptions to this rule but it is evident that you have too many of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one `NavigationView` in your app.  Delete the `NavigationView` from your child views and only provide the list of `NavigationLink`s. Those `NavigationLink`s will be pushed onto the stack created by the original `NavigationView`.